# How can you discover which user you are through an environment variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to know the user name through using the environment variable in pl/sql? How can I do that in oracle

Answer (score 1):

you can query for it

```
select user from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Select sys_context('userenv','os_user') from dual;
```

More : [sys_context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the user name through using the environment variable in pl/sql?

- **PL/SQL**

In PL/SQL, you could directly use the **USER** function to get the user_id of the current session.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    user_id VARCHAR2(30);
  3  BEGIN
  4    user_id := USER;
  5    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Current user is : '||user_id);
  6  END;
  7  /
Current user is : LALIT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- **SQL*Plus**

In SQL*Plus, to simply show the user_id of the current session, you could do:

```
SQL> SHOW USER
USER is "LALIT"
SQL>
```

- **SQL**

In SQL:

```
SQL> SELECT USER FROM dual;

USER
---------------------------
LALIT

SQL>
```